# Can I choose which constructor Unity will use?

Tags: c#, unity-container

Is it possible to specify in a Unity Resolve which constructor Unity should use?

The object I am trying to create may look something like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    [UseWhenSunny]
    public MyObject(InputOne one)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Chose constructor one");
    }

    [UseWhenRaining]
    public MyObject(InputTwo two)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Chose constructor two");
    }
}

public class InputOne
{
}

public class InputTwo
{
}
```

My construction could be something like this:

```
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterInstance(new InputTwo());
        var myObject = container.Resolve<MyObject>();
```

I can find the correct ConstructorInfo easily enough, but I have not figured out how to force Unity to use this specific constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a strange construct when you use different constructors for states within a game/program. If you want to pass two different class types, you could use inheritance for that. You need a common ancestor because `InputOne` and `InputTwo` only shares `Object` as common ancestor. So you need to specify a *new* base class. In this base class you write the common functionality/definition.

Here is an example:

```
public abstract class InputBase
{
    public abstract void Show();
}

public class InputOne : InputBase
{
    public override void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Show one");
    }

}

public class InputTwo : InputBase
{
    public override void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Show two");
    }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public MyObject(InputBase input)
    {
        // because InputOne and InputTwo can be casted to their base class
        // they both can be passed as InputBase.
        // InputBase defines the Show method which their derived ones must
        // implement (abstract).
        input.Show();
    }
}
```

See [Inheritance (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/inheritance)

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. My real problem is way more complex than this. One constructor may have 5 different input objects and another may have 7. And none of them share inheritance. I was only trying to illustrate the problem with this simple example Apologies if I failed in that.

Comment: @TorbenNielsen what if you pass a `Dictionary<string, object>` so you can lookup by name?

Comment: Thanks again Jeroen. Yes, I suppose I could do that. Or i could just pass the unity-container MyObject can just resolve the input it needs from the container. Yes, I guess that would work.